Checkmarx issue : Client DOM Stored XSS
I am facing a Client DOM Stored XSS issue with below code where on ajax success I am getting data as a return value :
function getGridData(sURL, sData, sErrorMsg){
                showElement($('#loadingBG')); 
                $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: sURL,
                          data:sData, //Data sent to controller//
                          dataType:"json",             
                          cache: false,
                          async:false,
                          loadtext: "Loading...", 
                          on403: function(t) {
                                location.href= contextPath+'/sequencedWP';
                              },
                          error: function(data, err){
                          //alert("AJAX Error: "+err);
                                  if(data.status==403){
                                        location.href= contextPath+'/sequencedWP';
                                    }else{
                                         alert("AJAX Error: "+JSON.stringify(data));
                                    }
                          },            
                          success: function(data){
                              isLocked = false;
                              if(sURL.indexOf("exportToExcel")== -1){
                                  $("#sequencedWPSummaryTbl").jqGrid('GridUnload'); //Unload Old Grid//
                                    $("#sequencedWPTbl").jqGrid('GridUnload'); //Unload Old Grid//
                                    $("#sequencedWPSummaryTbl1").jqGrid('GridUnload');
                                  //  $(".ui-pg-input").val(data.filterBean.currentPage);
                                     sortOrder = data.filterBean.orderByDirection;
                                     searchParam = data.filterBean.filterParam;
                                     sortColumnName = data.filterBean.columnName;
                                     successMsg = data.successMsg;
                                     searchJsonData = data.filterBean.searchData;
                                     idsOfSelectedRows = new Array();
                                     containerList= data.containerList;
                                     shipWithId = new Array();
                                     pickWaveId = new Array();
                                     pickWaveIdAll = new Array();
                                     wpTypes = new Array();
                                     statusIds = new Array();
                                     pickSeqArray = new Array();
                                     filterData='';
                                     if (typeof searchJsonData != 'undefined' && ''!=searchJsonData)
                                        {
                                             filterData =  JSON.parse(searchJsonData);



The checmarx scanner shows error as : 
The method generateGrid embeds untrusted data in generated output with $, at line 3 of sequencedWorkPackage.js file. This untrusted data is embedded into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the generated web-page.

Line number code :
1 function generateGrid(workPackage){   
2       var fscList = '{';
3           $(containerList).each(function() {
4               fscList += this.containerId + ':"' + this.containerTypeCode + '",';
5           });
6           fscList += '}';
        

The response coming from ajax call is sent using :
model.addAttribute("jsonData",gridData.getJSONString());

response.getWriter().write(gridData.getJSONString());   

Tried using jQuery instead of $ at line 3 in above . Didn't work.
Can you please help with this issue.

In general, since containerList is coming from the response object, it should be sanitized before concatenating it straight into the response. A malicious value could change the structure of the response (JSON) you are trying to construct.
Using encodeURIComponent or encodeURI should remove the result/alert:
fscList +=  encodeURIComponent(this.containerId) + ':"' + encodeURIComponent(this.containerTypeCode) + '",';
